typeid on QtWebEngine's internal type returning invalid reference
The typeid operator returns an invalid reference on an object from QtWebEngine. This behavior is unexpected according to the definition of typeid.
Here is a sandbox reproducing the issue:
#include <QTimer>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QtWebEngineQuick/QtWebEngineQuick>
#include <QtWebEngineCore/QtWebEngineCore>
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts);
    QQuickWindow::setGraphicsApi(QSGRendererInterface::OpenGLRhi);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    class EventFilter : public QObject{
    public:
        using QObject::QObject;
        QSet<const QMetaObject*> visited;
        bool eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent*) override {
            const QMetaObject* mo = obj->metaObject();
            if(!visited.contains(mo)){
                visited.insert(mo);
                const std::type_info& typeInfo = typeid(*obj);
                // the following action may crash:
               // typeInfo.name();
               // prove it by checking the reference for validity:
                const std::type_info* typeInfoPtr = &typeInfo;
                if(mo && typeInfoPtr)
                    qWarning("metaobject: %s, typeid: %p (%s)", mo->className(), typeInfoPtr, typeInfoPtr->name());
                else if(mo)
                    qWarning("metaobject: %s, typeid: nullptr", mo->className());
                else
                    qWarning("metaobject: nullptr, typeid: nullptr");
            }
            return false;
        }
    } eventFilter;
    app.installEventFilter(&eventFilter);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    QObject::connect(
&engine,
&QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreationFailed,
&app,
        []() { QCoreApplication::exit(-1); },
        Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.loadData(R"(
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtWebEngineApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 500
    height: 400
    WebEngineView {
        id: webView
        anchors.fill: parent
        url: http://www.qt.io
    }
}
)");
    QTimer::singleShot(2000, &app, QCoreApplication::quit);
    return app.exec();
}

This code produces the output:
metaobject: QtWebEngineCore::RenderWidgetHostViewQtDelegateItem, typeid: nullptr

Successive operations on typeInfo result in a crash.
Is this a bug within Qt or Cromium or in macOS' typeid operator implementation?

What line has the crash?  What info does your debugger show about the crash?

Thanks for the help @Eljay!  Please see my revised post.  I'll try to get some debugger details.

RTTI is disabled in QtWebEngineCore. typeid(*obj).name() also would crash.
